# How many parameters can switch case accept in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

The following code contains more than 1 switch parameter. How many can it accept?
The output of the code is 2. Why is it 2? 
Is there a priority concept when more than 1 parameters are used in switch case?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int ch;
    printf("enter a value btw 1 to 2:");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch (ch, ch + 1)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("1\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("2");
        break;
    }
}
```

/*
Value entered by user is 1
*/

Comment: it's just same as `switch (ch + 1)`. Not sure what's the point in writing it this way?

Comment: "*The output of the code is 2. Why is it 2?*" And this input is?

Comment: the input for ch is 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Switch takes an expression.
2. `ch, ch + 1` is an expression using the comma operator.
3. The comma operator evaluates the left hand side of the comma first, and discards the result. Then it evaluates the right hand side, and returns that result.

For more information about the comma operator:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)
- [C 2011 Section 6.5.17](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17)

Comment: And since the first expression has no side effect, it's completely useless (equivalent to `switch (ch + 1)`). Whoever wrote that code needs a stern talk about readability.

Answer (score 5):

You can only pass one argument to the switch statement. What happened in that code was the use of the comma operator, which evaluates both expressions and returns the second.

So the result is equivalent to using `switch (ch+1)` in that code.

Comment: This is a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: @Vad I honestly disagree. This question, although a duplicate, is complete and unambiguous, and this answer therefore clarifies OP's misconceptions on the matter. Besides, the accepted answer says roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in the expression in the `switch` statement.

**6.5.17 Comma operator:**

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.<sup>114)</sup>

*left operand(s) must have a side effect, if it doesn't, then it serves no purpose*. In expression `ch, ch + 1`, there is no side effect takes place in the left operand `ch` therefore it serves no purpose.

Your compiler should raise a warning:

```
[Warning] left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

Comment: 1+ for reference to the Standard, as well as for providing the warning to be expected ...